# Laptop turns off upon high CPU usage with very busy fan noise

Tags: 12.04, fan

My [Serval laptop](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/06/system76-serval-professional-review) (vendor's, System76's, website no longer has info) has suddenly started immediate turn-off power recently. It's happened at least twice in last 2 days. Any idea is appreciated and please tell me which log files you need to investigate so that I'm happy to provide those.

I can only describe the situation non-numerically b/c I didn't record anything when it occurred but:

- CPU usage is high due to the app I started (roughly, the usage of all 4 cores is more than 75%, less than 100% on Gnome System Monitor)
- Application program running was a simulator for robotics (called Gazebo), which after a few minutes of running the phenomenon occurs. I've used the same tool before on this machine so shouldn't be the matter.
- Noise of the fan was the one of the busiest
- Memory usage was about 50%

Not sure if it's related but after I've upgraded to Precise, the fan has been making more noise even when the CPU usage is very low.

Environment: Ubuntu 12.04 (originally 11.04 upon purchase, then 11.10), Kernel 3.2.0-30-generic, Core i7 2GHz x 8, 11.7GB RAM, GeForce GTX 560M

Thanks.

Comment: Does it have a graphic card?

Comment: @green7 thx I updated OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As in this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2055079&p=12698836#post12698836), I figured out by myself that the fan was clogged.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look into system monitor if you can see some process or aplication that is making your computer so busy.

Comment: As in my description, the source of high computation is known - a simulator. It's inevitable that the simulator works very busy. But still computer should not shuts down all of sudden no matter how busy it works.

Comment: Yes it should. It's a safety fuse against heat. You simply need to make better ventilation for your pc.